# Reading .npz files from R

Tags: r

I save `.npz` files from Python and wanna read it in R.

I tried using `npyLoad` function but i get this error

```
library(RcppCNPy)
Data <- npyLoad("xx.npz")
```

`Error in npyLoad("xx.npz") : header ended improperly`

I think this happens because i saved my data from Python in `Data` array but i can't specify this in `npyLoad`.

So, is there away to read this compressed npy files in R. ?

Comment: See the [existing issue ticket at GitHub](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppcnpy/issues/8); someone needs to implement it.  I never needed it, so it is not part of my package (yet).  CNPy supports it...

Comment: Thanks for replying, So i've to wait till someone develop function for it ?

Comment: As the saying goes in Open Souce land: if you are the one with the itch, maybe you should be the one writing this (or fund someone writing it for you).

Comment: Thanks alot. today was my first time using Python but i'll try to spend time to develop it.

Answer (score 5):

The issue linked by Dirk has a new comment that explains a workaround. The main idea is to use the reticulate package to access the numpy functionality.

```
library(reticulate)
np <- import("numpy")

npz1 <- np$load("foo1.npz")
npz1$files
npz1$f[["arr_0"]]
npz1$f[["arr_1"]]
```