# Load NPZ sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, numpy, sparse-matrix, reticulate, npz-file

How can I read a sparse matrix that I have saved with Python as a `*.npz` file in R? I already came across two answers* on Stackoverflow but neither seems to do the job in my case.

The [data set](https://gigamove.rwth-aachen.de/en/download/0e4852a59d528dee403f3f0b462c89e7) was created with Python from a Pandas data frame via:

```
scipy.sparse.save_npz(
     "data.npz",
     scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(DataFrame.values)
     )
```

It seems like the first steps for importing the data set in R are as follows.

```
library(reticulate)
np = import("numpy")
npz1 <- np$load("data.npz")
```

However, this does not yield a data frame yet.

*1 [Load sparce NumPy matrix into R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65230890/5696601)

*2 [Reading .npz files from R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726507/5696601)

Comment: The dataframe was not saved.  A sparse CSR representation of the numpy array from its `values` was written. The npz is a zip archive of 4 arrays.  You can 'extract' them with a OS `zip` tool.

Comment: `scipy.sparse.save_npz(name)` will create a new `csr` matrix, not a numpy array or dataframe.

Comment: In Python I can laod the data via `scipy.sparse.load_npz("data.npz" )`. Can I also load it in R?

Comment: Can you load those 4 arrays?  Can you make a `csr` format sparse matrix from scratch.  I'm not an R user so can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot access your dataset, so I can only speak from experience. When I try loading a sparse CSR matrix with numpy, it does not work ; the class of the object is `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile`, which I can't use in R.

The way I found to import the matrix into an R object, as has been said in a post you've [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161354/load-sparce-numpy-matrix-into-r/65230890#65230890), is to use scipy.sparse.

```r
library(reticulate)
scipy_sparse = import("scipy.sparse")
csr_matrix = scipy_sparse$load_npz("path_to_your_file")
```

csr_matrix, which was a [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) object in Python (Compressed Sparse Row matrix), is automatically converted into a `dgRMatrix` from the R package `Matrix`. Note that if you had used `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` in Python, you would get a `dgCMatrix` (Compressed Sparse Column matrix). The actual function doing the hardwork converting the Python object into something R can use is [`py_to_r.scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/ebb0ea1d1478c47e6fd86000827854c84fb33645/R/conversion.R#L526), from the `reticulate` package.

If you want to convert the `dgRMatrix` into a data frame, you can simply use

```r
df <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(csr_matrix))
```

although this might not be the best thing to do memory-wise if your dataset is big.

I hope this helped!